# Groupby in sparkR not giving desired results

Tags: r, sparkr

I have created a data frame out of `mtcars`. I do a group by `gear` and `cyl`. then i calculate max for `hp` and `disp`. something is going wrong in group by as there should be 8 groups in there. while i get only 6 groups.

```
library(sparkR)
xx=as.DataFrame(sqlContext, data = mtcars)

head(agg(groupBy(xx, "gear", "cyl"), hp = 'max'))
  gear cyl max(hp)
1    3   8     245
2    5   4     113
3    3   4      97
4    4   4     109
5    5   6     175
6    3   6     110
```

**Update 1:**

I have another query, in the documentation of `groupby` we have an example as:

```
## Examples

## Not run: 
  # Compute the average for all numeric columns grouped by department.
  avg(groupBy(df, "department"))

  # Compute the max age and average salary, grouped by department and gender.
  agg(groupBy(df, "department", "gender"), salary="avg", "age" -> "max")

## End(Not run)
```

similarly for mtcars i came up with

```
agg(groupBy(xx, "gear", "cyl"), qsec ="avg", "disp" -> "max")
```

Firstly my understanding is that we get max of `disp`, but the code doesn't seem to work. It gives out error as follows. Second thing is that the code work with an `=` in place of `->`. So is there a typo or something?

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘groupBy’ for signature ‘"function"’

My SparkR version is `SparkR_1.6.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aggregation is well, but you are adding a 'head' in first, it will show you just the first 6 lines . You need to replace it by a collect.
like this:

```
df <- as.DataFrame(mtcars)
gp = agg(groupBy(df, df$gear, df$cyl), hp = 'max')
collect(gp)
```

Just a remark, i am using spark 2.0.2

Comment: Oh. how could i miss `head`. Thanks for the advise on `collect`.

Comment: Please can you tell what is your spark version, and if the significant of "disp" -> "max" is just to get the max of the disp variable, you just need to replace it by an '=' .

Comment: Actually in the documentation of `groupBy` this particular example is given.  I think it must be a typo.

Comment: Until proof to the contrary, I thik also that is a typo

Comment: We can settle with that. Thanks for your help.